# Python Asyncio - no time saved on function call inside dictionary

Tags: python, time, python-asyncio

I'm trying to use asyncio to save time on processing the values of a dictionary but I'm its not saving any time.

```
import asyncio
import time


async def get_time(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    return str(t)

async def ff():
    f = dict(
        d=await get_time(2),
        e=await get_time(2),
        f=await get_time(2),
        g=await get_time(2),
        h=await get_time(2),
        i=await get_time(2),
    )
    print(f)

t0 = time.time()
asyncio.run(ff())
print(time.time()-t0)
```

Output:

```
12.008311986923218
```

Expected Output is *sub* 2 seconds since I expect the code to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await coroutine()` waits for the coroutine to complete and only then proceeds. Despite appearances, calling `await` in multiple arguments to the dict constructor is no different than calling them in sequence, so your `ff` function could also be written as follows with exactly the same meaning:

```
async def ff():
    # get_time() executed in sequence
    _d = await get_time(2)
    _e = await get_time(2)
    _f = await get_time(2)
    _g = await get_time(2)
    _h = await get_time(2)
    _i = await get_time(2)
    f = dict(d=_d, e=_e, f=_f, g=_g, h=_h, i=_i)
    print(f)
```

What you want to do is submit all instances of `get_time()` to the event loop and then wait for them to finish, collecting the results. This can be done by invoking `asyncio.create_task()` on every `get_time()`, or by calling `asyncio.gather()`, designed for precisely that purpose. For example:

```
async def ff():
    # get_time() executed in parallel
    d, e, f, g, h, i = await asyncio.gather(
        get_time(2),
        get_time(2),
        get_time(2),
        get_time(2),
        get_time(2),
        get_time(2),
    )
    f = dict(d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g, h=h, i=i)
    print(f)
```